# How to parse non-default (non-english) time formats including full month names in d3.js?

Tags: javascript, datetime, parsing, d3.js, localization

I want to parse dates and times in d3.js, that contain full german month names, e.g. `21-Juni-10:29`, using a d3 parser.
By default, d3 parsers use english to parse full and abbreviated month names like `June` or `Feb`.

I tried loading the german *locale* file using d3.json, as described in the [d3-time-format Readme](https://github.com/d3/d3-time-format#installing).
I also tried the russian example, but couldn't get it to work either.

The following sources were used in a html file:

```
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3-time.v1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3-time-format.v2.min.js"></script>
```

Here is my example code:

```
d3.json("https://unpkg.com/d3-time-format@2/locale/de-DE.json", function(error, locale) {
    if (error) throw error;
    d3.timeFormatDefaultLocale(locale);

    var parseMailSendTime = d3.timeParse("%d-%B-%H:%M")

    console.log("21-Juni-10:29 is parsed to " + parseMailSendTime("21-Juni-10:29"));
});
```

I expect to to get a parsed date object (for now in the console), but don't get any logs in the console.

Comment: You are using d3v5 - this version changed d3.json to use promises: try `d3.json("url").then(function(locale) {  .... })`. Your code works for me with this change. Unchanged, it works for me with d3v4

Comment: Thanks, @AndrewReid ! Is there a way to mark this question answered and give you reputation for your indication of my mistake?